# Wie nennt man den »Hauptteil« eines Hauses (im Gegensatz zu Dach und Keller)?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein Wort für den Teil eines klassischen Hauses, der einen oberirdischen Quader formt, bzw. das Haus ohne Dach- und Kellergeschosse:

[image: Skizze]

Aufgekommen ist die Frage zum einen während einer allgemeinen, laienhaften Unterhaltung über den Aufbau eines Hauses, z. B.:

> Das Haus hat zwei Wohnungen im *Hauptteil,* eine im Dachgeschoss und eine im Keller.

Zum anderen entstand Bedarf nach dem Wort beim Bauen eines Hauses aus Spielklötzen.

Die beste Antwort, die ich bisher finden konnte, war *[Baukörper](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauk%C3%B6rper),* was aber das gesamte Innere erfasst.

Comment: Entspricht in den meisten Häuser der "Wohnfläche", welche Keller und Dachräume nicht beinhaltet. Ausnahme, wenn das Dachgeschoss ausgebaut ist. Ich bezweifel aber, dass du das Wort suchst...

Comment: _Die Wohngeschosse_ würden den Bereich beschreiben. Meines Wissens (ich habe Architektur studiert) gibt es zumindest keinen allgemein gültigen Ausdruck.

Comment: Ich bezweifle, dass es dafür einen eigenen Begriff gibt: je nach Dachform und ggf. Höhe des Kniestocks beinhaltet der oberirdische Quader einen mehr oder weniger großen Teil des Dachgeschosses, und ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, welchen Zweck dieser Begriff dann erfüllen könnte. Oder anders gesagt: das "klassische Haus", von dem Du ausgehst, ist so vielgestaltig, dass es diese Aufteilung nicht hergibt.

Comment: Für welchen Kontext brauchst du das denn? Wenn's nicht fachlich sein muss, dann vielleicht "das eigentliche Haus"? Oder vielleicht "Rumpf des Hauses". Gibt auch ein paar Fundstellen für, aber nicht viele   https://www.google.de/search?q="rumpf+des+hauses"&client=opera&hs=g7M&biw=1366&bih=642&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAGoVChMIzI6yqo77xgIVCHEUCh3FJwZ3&dpr=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hausschaft* oder *Gebäudeschaft*, siehe Wikipedia [Turmschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmschaft) , am Ende des Artikels. Alternativ auch *Normalgeschosse*, siehe [Geschossbezeichnungen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschoss_%28Architektur%29#Geschossbezeichnungen).